# I can't make my material transparent in Blender 2.80

Tags: materials, node-editor, transparency, eevee-render-engine

I can't seem to have my material turn transparent in blender 2.80. Heres some screenshots, is there something I'm missing?

This is how it looks in EEVEE:

[image: material sample in EEVEE]

Here is my node setup:

[image: node setup]

Comment: using Eevee you have to activate it per material in the material menue. See here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134368/opacity-of-an-object-in-2-8

Comment: Thank you for solving It!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make the object transparent, their are 2 ways to do that:

1. Use transparent material (as you have already used), Add it to a mix shader whith the respective shader you want it to mix with and change the blend mode for the object to "Alpha blend".
   [image: Transparent-shader]

Now, you use this method when you want to create an object with just transparency, that means without any reflection (that doesn't quite exists in real world). Every transparent material has refraction and if you want your material reflect like glass you can use the second method.

2. Using a glass shader. It won't directly reflect the changes right away, you need to enable "Screen space Refraction" for both the scene and the material you. Then you need to change the refractive index of the material to the one you wish for, or just keep it anything else than 0.
   [image: Glass-shader]
   Scene settings to enable refraction[image: Scene-settings]

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: Happy to help! :)