# Opaque plastic in Blender

Tags: modeling

[image]

I have been trying to produce a polytunnel in Blender, without success. Can anyone please let me know how to make a tunnel covered in opaque plastic.

Comment: What us a "polytunnel", could you illustrate with some reference pictures?

Comment: Hi. Please read [these tips on how to improve your questions](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please)

Comment: Hi Duarte and All, I have added an image of what I a model trying to build in Blender. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks. Brian

Comment: What part of the modelling process are you having trouble with? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Blender Stack exchange. As wikipedia says

> A polytunnel (also known as a polyhouse, hoop greenhouse or hoophouse, grow tunnel or high tunnel) is a tunnel typically made from steel and covered in polythene, usually semi-circular, square or elongated in shape.

I tried making a low-poly tunnel with least efforts quickly, it looks like this :
[image]

The way I achieved this is by

1. Modelling the polytunnel in the way I wanted.
2. Adding a transparent shader/glass shader as the material to make that plastic covering.

Here's the node setup for the material:
[image]

You can also use the glass shader, here's the usage: [I can't make my material transparent in Blender 2.80](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165385/i-cant-make-my-material-transparent-in-blender-2-80/165389#165389)

Comment: Ah, as I a man still quite new to Blender, your illustration of the nodes settings above has helped me to fulfil this task. Kindest regards to you Harshvardhan for your help.

Comment: Happy to help! :-)