# Making a mesh transparent or decreasing opacity so objects inside will be visible

Tags: mesh, transparency, wireframe

Made a Fire mesh in blender

But I wanted to make it transparent so that the inside object can be seen

But I tried all possible ways to make it transparent

There are certain tutorials to add transparencey but the version is totally different
There is no transparent option in Blender  2.8+

```
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134368/opacity-of-an-object-in-2-8
```

Tried the method mentioned in this thread as well
but its no use

Is there any way where we can decrease the opacity of mesh/object in the latest version of blender   ??

Attached blender object (dropbox)
please have a look

[Opacity of an object in 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134368/opacity-of-an-object-in-2-8)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2mdki8ell8saf2q/firefix2%20-%20Copy.blend?dl=0

Comment: The method will depend on the renderer you are using : Eevee, Cycles or Workbench (or a 3rd party)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your blend mode to "alpha blend" and you will get:

[image]

I unplugged the fac of your mix shader so you can slide the fac and see what happens.