# Change Object Opacity in Blender 2.93

Tags: objects

Wondering how to change the opacity of an object in version 2.9. I've selected the object and have tried going to the Object Properties panel but I don't see where to adjust the opacity. I would just like to change the opacity of this object to 50% so that it's see-through. I've tried switching between Object Mode and Edit Mode, but still no difference.

[image]

[image]

Note that I'm not talking about transparency here I.e. I don't think that I should have to do everything that's listed in the answers [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134368/opacity-of-an-object-in-2-8). Turning on Wireframe mode isn't what I'm looking for either - there has to be a way to adjust the opacity somewhere - right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're talking about in the 3D viewport (solid mode), use the X-Ray settings:

[image: Xray]

If you want to do it in Rendered preview mode, you can do it by using the object's *alpha*. If using EEVEE, don't forget to change the *Blend Mode* to something other than *Opaque*.

[image: Alpha]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the *X-Ray* and EEVEE material alpha methods, you can also control an object's opacity in *Solid* view mode through the color options controlled by *Viewport Shading* overlays. There are two main modes: *Material*-based, and *Object*-based.

**Viewport Shading > Color > Material**

When shading mode is set to *Material*, color of the objects in the scene are controlled by *Properties > Material Settings > Viewport Display > Color*. The color wheel here has an *Alpha* channel you can turn down for transparency. By default it's an off-white color, which you can see on the monkeys at the back. Obviously, this setting only shows up if your object *has* a material. All objects using that material in the active slot (like the two big monkeys here) will be colored the same:

[image]

**Viewport Shading > Color > Object**

When shading mode is set to *Object*, colors can be decided on an individual basis via *Properties > Object Settings > Viewport Display > Color*.

[image]

If there are no texture maps or vertex colors assigned to an object, *Vertex* mode will default to the *Object* settings, and *Texture* mode will default to the *Material* settings.